# How to retrieve data from orientdb database to a list from two clusters that are linked with a edge?

Tags: java, orientdb

How to retrieve data from orientdb database to a list from two clusters that are linked with a edge? is there any sample code?

Comment: not actually clear, could you provide a practical example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You canno't link to another cluster with an edge. The id's could not be unique from one cluster to another